# segmentation fault php when using pcntl

Tags: php, segmentation-fault

I am executing  from the command line on OSX El Capitan 10.11.3, PHP 5.5.32 with pcntl module enabled the following PHP script.

```
<?php
declare(ticks = 1);

function mySigHandler() {
    switch ($signo) {
     case SIGTERM:
         // handle shutdown tasks
         exit;
         break;
     case SIGHUP:
         // handle restart tasks
         break;
     case SIGUSR1:
         echo "Caught SIGUSR1...\n";
         break;
     default:
         // handle all other signals
    }
}

pcntl_signal(SIGINT, "mySigHandler");
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, "mySigHandler");
pcntl_signal(SIGHUP, "mySigHandler");
for ($n = 0; ; usleep(500000)) // 0.5 seconds
    echo ++$n, "\n";
?>
```

What I am trying to achieve here is a typical signal handling script that will react to different signals appropriately. However, when I try to kill the script using CTRL-C, kill -1, kill -2 or kill -15, I always get  segmentation fault as a result.
What is even more frustrating is the fact that I executed the same script on a different machine and the results were the ones I was hoping for in the first place. Any ideas why this segmentation fault keeps happening and how I could solve it?

Comment: Some Questions: Do the machines have the same PHP version? Did you check [bugs.php.net](https://bugs.php.net/)? Based on Linux, I do not know whether these tool are available in OS X as well: did you run the script with strace? Did you try to gdb it? First thing I would try is use another PHP version.

Comment: They do not have the same PHP version. The problem with my machine is that it has installed different PHP versions before I started using it. PHP version from the command line is different than Apache's PHP version and different from the PHP version that background scripts are using...

Comment: Fixed it by installing a new PHP version (5.6.17) using HomeBrew. I am still ignorant on why the previous PHP produced this segmentation fault though.